# How can I load CSS Modules with a *runtime* unique hash?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, css-in-js

I have 2 micro frontends, which share the same component library. This creates specificity bugs, because it breaks the order of style definition. For example:

Suppose we have these styles:

```css
.card { padding: 1rem, border-radius: 1rem }
.profile { padding: 2rem }
```

1. MicroFrontend 1 uses the Card component `<div class="card">`, and the Profile component `<Card class="profile">` which results in `<div class="card profile">`
2. Microfrontend 2 only uses Card.

In this scenario, styles from the second microfrontend class `.card` will override the styles defined in `.profile`. Resulting in a profile with a padding of 1rem.

In order to solve this, I want to switch to a more CSS-in-JS approach, without having to actually port the code, which is currently defined in per-component CSS modules.

I want styles to be injected at runtime instead of at build time. And I want those styles to be unique at runtime. Is there any library that allows this (importing the styles from a .modules.scss file)?

Comment: is there a reason not to have three css files? one for shared styles, one for fe1 specific styles, and one for fe2 specific styles?

Comment: Using **.card.profile** could fix the specificity issue.

Comment: dqhendricks The 2 frontends are using the same component library, which is a separate npm package. They have no controls over the styles defined in the library.

Comment: @imvain2 Yes that would solve this specific scenario, but there are hundreds of edge cases, and potential specificity problems like this, I'd like to solve them all together.